# 'CRM on demand' change date to the first of the month in custom field

Tags: crm

I have been searching the Oracle developers forum and the rest of Google to no avail for this question.

I have created a custom field in a report that shows the date a new tender was created. I want to change this date to be the first of the month for that date.

I have tried using `Trunc(mydate, 'month')` to change the date but this throws an error.

Comment: there are tons of CRM's out there. Salesforce, Dynamics, and other providers. You should edit to question to add the relevant tags and a [mcve]

Comment: I know, but Oracle CRM on Demand is not one of them and I wasn't able to add the tag myself.